# RSA cryptography outputs wrong values

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

I am making a simple program to encrypt/decrypt plain text with RSA cryptography in c#.
The problem is that my encryption result and decryption result are identically the same.
I've debugged my code a lot and if I use as starting values p = 3 and q = 11, the result of E = 3, and result of D = 7. As I said before, encryption and decryption return values are same, I've checked my encryption and decryption methods twice, they're properly written using formulas.
Could someone explain me what am I doing wrong while finding E or D?
Just in case, f = φ (n).

Here's a method to find E:

```
 public BigInteger GetE(BigInteger f) 
    {
        int value = 0;

        for(int i = 2; i < n2; i++)
        {             
           if (gcd(f, i) == 1)
            {
                value = i;
                break;

            }          
        }
        return value;

    }

    BigInteger GetGCD(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
    {

        if (a == 0)
            return b;
        return gcd(b % a, a);
    }
```

Here's a method to find D:

```
 BigInteger GetPrivateKey(BigInteger f, BigInteger e)
    {
        BigInteger d = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= e; i++)
        {
            d = (1 + i * f) / e; 
            if (d % 1 == 0)
            {                   
                break;
            }
        }
        return d;
    }
```

Encryption method(Array is declared as global):

```
 public BigInteger[] GetEncryptedValues(int length)
    {
        encryptedValues = new BigInteger[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < textValues.Length; i++)
        {
            BigInteger k = GetPow(textValues[i], e);
            k %= n;

            encryptedValues[i] = k;
        }

        return encryptedValues;
    }
```

Decryption:

```
 privateKey = GetPrivateKey(f, e);

        BigInteger[] decryptedValues = new BigInteger[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < encryptedValues.Length; i++)
        {
            BigInteger k = GetPow(encryptedValues[i], privateKey);
            k %= n;
            decryptedValues[i] = k;
        }
```

GetPow method:

```
 public static BigInteger GetPow(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
    {
        BigInteger result = 1;
        for (BigInteger i = 1; i < b; i++)
            result *= a;
        return result;
    }
```

String to bytes:

```
 public byte[] GetTextValues(string text)
    {
        byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

        return asciiBytes;
    }
```

Comment: These numbers are correct, show your encryption/dec code

Comment: I've updated my post with encrypt/decrypt code.

Comment: `privateKey = GetPrivateKey(e, f);` f? What is f? Please use reasonably standard notation if you won't use descriptive variable names. It also appears that you've reversed the arguments to `GetPrivateKey`

Comment: f is simply φ (n). To me it was a understandable variable, sorry for being careless while naming variables. Thank you for finding a mistake in the given code, the output right now is a bit different. The values are different comparing encryption and decryption values. Unfortunately, the output is not the right one, this did not fixed the decryption problem. I've edited the code.

Comment: Check `GetPow`. Let the loop start with `i = 0`.

Comment: @Topaco I've changed the loop iteration value starting from 0, but the decryption return value is still wrong

Comment: You should debug your program step by step and compare the result of each step generated by the program with the expected result to isolate the error(s).